# WKInterfaceController with modal segue

Tags: objective-c, watchos-2

I'm presenting a `WKInterfaceController` with a modal segue from another interface controller.

When you tap a row in the table of this modal interface controller how do I dismiss this interface controller and communicate back to presenting interface controller?

This is my current storyboard setup.

```
[Root] -> [Push 1] -> [Push 2] -> [Modal]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are friendly with `NSNotificationCenter`.

At first, There is no way to access parent interface controller except when the parent controller is root controller.

Root controller can be accessed by:

```
[WKExtension sharedExtension].rootInterfaceController
```

Basically, direct communications between interface controller are not recommended. Use `NotificationCenter` instead. So in your modal controller, do something like this:

```
-(void) didTapARowInTable
{
    NSNotificationCenter* nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc postNotificationName:@"UseDidTapARowFromModal"
                      object:self
                    userInfo:@{/* data that will be needed 
                                  to present new modal here */}];

    // close current modal.
    [self dismissController];
}
```

Second, Any UI code in `WKInterfaceController` will not work when it is not active one. All the `WKInterfaceObject`s are query object that are connected with real remote UIs(You know the storyboard files are located in separated bundle). When the remote UI is not shown, interface controller for it is deactivated, and It can't send UI modifying query to real UI Objects anymore. It can only modify it's own state when it is not activated.

So parent controller should not access any UI API until it got activated(such as showing a new modal or change WKInterface Objects). So, In your parent controller do things like this:

```
-(void)didReceiveTapRowNotification:(NSNotification*) note
{
    // just remember task to perform, don't use any UI code here.
    _taskInfo = note.userInfo;
}

-(void)willActivate
{
    [super willActivate];

    // check scheduled task and do it if exists.
    if(_taskInfo){
        [self presentControllerWithName:@"modal-name" 
                                context:_taskInfo];
        _taskInfo = nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This does work but the presenting view controller is not the root view controller so I don't see where I would remove this observer when the presenting view controller (Push 2) is popped.  I edited my post with the setup.

Comment: Use same strategy. Since there is no completion call back support for `popController`, The only way to pick a point when the `Push2` is popped is `[Push1 activated]`. When you pushing push2 from push1, you have to store some state variable that indicate whether push2 was presented or not to determine appropriate behavior on `[Push1 activated]`.

Comment: I ended up just holding the notification observer in a static variable for the `Push 2` interface controller and then removing the observer before adding it again in subsequent `-awakeFromContext:` calls.  Thanks for your help!